# css margin not working without padding

Tags: html, css

according to the code , i want to marge the inner div "smedia" down ,it's not working unless i'm giving the outer div "layout" a padding value , need an explanation for that

also i figured that this can be solved by giving the "inner div" inline-block value **ONLY** not even block value , i need an explanation for that also

```css
h1,h2,h3,p,div,section,header,footer,section,article,nav,ul,html,body
{
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

li{list-style-position: inside;list-style-type: none;}
body{background-color:white}
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
a{text-decoration: none;}


.header-text{text-align:center;}
.layout{width: 60%;margin: auto; background-color: #4DC1E8;height:300px;padding-top: 0px;}
.smedia{width:200px;background-color: antiquewhite;margin-top: 90px;}
.logo{border-right-style: solid;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="p3css.css" >
</head>
<body>
   <h1 class="header-text">Clean Profile Widget</h1>
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="smedia">
            <span class="logo">FB</span>
            <span class="logo">TWR</span>

        </div>
    </div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

**when giving padding**

```css
h1,h2,h3,p,div,section,header,footer,section,article,nav,ul,html,body
{
    
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

li{list-style-position: inside;list-style-type: none;}
body{background-color:white}
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
a{text-decoration: none;}


.header-text{text-align:center;}
.layout{width: 60%;margin: auto; background-color: #4DC1E8;height:300px;padding-top: 1px;}
.smedia{width:200px;background-color: antiquewhite;margin-top: 90px;}
.logo{border-right-style: solid;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="p3css.css" >
</head>
<body>
   <h1 class="header-text">Clean Profile Widget</h1>
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="smedia">
            <span class="logo">FB</span>
            <span class="logo">TWR</span>

        </div>
    </div>
        
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: most of these solutions not explaining how their answers work , i specify that i need an explanation not a solution ...

Comment: the first answer of the duplicate question said `And check out collapsing margins while you're at it.` --> so click on the link about margin collpasing and you will understand everything ;)

Comment: From that link you can read `Two margins are adjoining if and only if:
both belong to in-flow block-level boxes that participate in the same block formatting context
no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them` --> so this concern only block elements and we need to have 0 padding, that's why adding padding will break this and making your element inline-block will also break this

Comment: thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you miss is `overflow: auto;`. Adding it to parent container makes margin work just fine.

The problem you faced is called margin-collapsing and it's pretty widely known. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) or [here](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/).

You can read about use of overflow and how it affects elements [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
p,
div,
section,
header,
footer,
section,
article,
nav,
ul,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  list-style-type: none;
}

body {
  background-color: white
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header-text {
  text-align: center;
}

.layout {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #4DC1E8;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.smedia {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  margin-top: 90px;
}

.logo {
  border-right-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="p3css.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="header-text">Clean Profile Widget</h1>
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="smedia">
      <span class="logo">FB</span>
      <span class="logo">TWR</span>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it's about margin-collpasing, so overflow is one fix but it's not the issue or the missing coe